# NetworkStream AsyncWrite speed

Tags: c#, async-await, asyncsocket

I am learning async socket programming and for a bit harder project I thought of creating a server for group chat. Managed to successfully do it, but I am not sure if performance is good enough and think I am doing something wrong.

Basically, I connect 400 users to the server and then send 1000 messages (message is 1kB, with prefixed length and rest is empty) from one of the users. Server needs to broadcast every message to all 400 users. There is List of NetworkStreams on the server and when server receives a message, it iterates through the list and calls stream.WriteAsync method. However, it seems to take server 40-50ms to send that message to all 400 users. During the test, server CPU usage is at ~4% and StressClient CPU usage is at ~55%. I was expecting it would be way faster than 40-50ms. Am I doing something wrong or is this maximum speed?

Here is server code (last 2 methods are the most relevant, ReceiveMessageAsync and SendToAllAsync)

```
private List<NetworkStream> connectedUsers = new List<NetworkStream>();
private int processedRequestsAmount = 0;
private Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

public ServerEngine()
{
}

public void Start(IPAddress ipAddress, int port)
{
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
    try
    {
        listener.Start();
        AcceptClientsAsync(listener);

        while (true)
        {
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            Console.WriteLine("Processed requests: " + processedRequestsAmount);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        listener.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Server stopped! Press ENTER to close application...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

private async Task AcceptClientsAsync(TcpListener listener)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            StartClientListenerAsync(client);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

private async Task StartClientListenerAsync(TcpClient client)
{
    using (client)
    {
        var buf = new byte[1024];
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        lock (connectedUsers)
        {
            connectedUsers.Add(stream);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(connectedUsers.Count + " users connected!");

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                await RecieveMessageAsync(stream, buf).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        connectedUsers.Remove(stream);
        Console.WriteLine("User disconnected.");
    }
}

private async Task RecieveMessageAsync(NetworkStream stream, byte[] readBuffer)
{
    int totalAmountRead = 0;

    // read header (length, 2 bytes total)
    while (totalAmountRead < 2)
    {
        totalAmountRead += await stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, totalAmountRead, 2 - totalAmountRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    short totalLength = BitConverter.ToInt16(readBuffer, 0);

    // read rest of the message
    while (totalAmountRead < totalLength)
    {
        totalAmountRead += await stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, totalAmountRead, totalLength - totalAmountRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    await SendToAllAsync(readBuffer, totalLength);
}

private async Task SendToAllAsync(byte[] buffer, short totalLength)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(connectedUsers.Count);
    if (processedRequestsAmount == 0)
    {
        sw.Start();
    }

    foreach (NetworkStream stream in connectedUsers)
    {
        tasks.Add(stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)); 
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

    processedRequestsAmount++;
    if (processedRequestsAmount == 1000)
    {
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Average time for sending 400 messages is {0} ms", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / 1000.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the 400 clients on the local machine or over the network? => 400 * 1Kb in 40ms is 10Mbytes/sec which is ~ line speed of 100Mbit Ethernet for example.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with async as far as I can tell. Also, your socket code looks correct which is a rare find on Stack Overflow.

Comment: if your expectations of speed are much higher are you aware of this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx "
Remarks
=> The NetworkStream class provides methods for sending and receiving data over Stream sockets in blocking mode. For more information about blocking versus nonblocking Sockets, see Using an Asynchronous Client Socket. => ie the asyncronicity of this model does not go very deep.

Comment: I usually use Sync Write because there is much difference between the Async and Sync methods.  There is a latency in the sending/receiving of the data so to get actual time I would average a number of samples.  The Write has to get transferred from the application to the network card which is done by the PC tick timer which could add 100 msec to transfer time.  The opposite occurs on the receiving end that the network card sends data up to the application through the tick timer adding additional delays.  TCP data is broken into datagrams of max 1500 bytes and time is required to pack/unpack.

Comment: @tolanj, unfortunately it's local machine

Comment: @jdweng, I just tried and it seems there is virtually no difference performance wise (in this case at least) between using sync write and async write which to me is pretty weird.

If I remove await Task.WhenAll and leave only stream.WriteAsync inside foreach loop, average sending time reduces to ~10ms, but memory skyrockets (before it would be steady at 10MB and now it jumps to 150MB and doesn't seem to go down ever), also CPU usage is much closer to what I expected (~20%). Is there a way to fix this memory leak and also are there any other bad sides of this approach?

Comment: The write is to an input stream for the time tick.  The timer tick take the stream and moves the data to the Ethernet card.  So Async and Sync are really just writing to an input stream which is memory.  Both should take the same time.  Because the memory doesn't go down doesn't necessarily imply a memory leak.  The memory isn't growing and will only be a leak if it doesn't go down when objects are disposed.  A lot of methods create hash tables that don't implement garbage collection.  As long as the hash tables don't constantly grow it is not really a leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out when I run the Server and ClientStressTest applications without debugging (ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio), it takes server only 5ms (CPU usage at ~30%) to send message to 400 users which is way better than I ever hoped for. Could someone explain to me why would attaching debugger slow things down so much?

Anyway, here is rest of the code if someone needs it to figure this out

ClientStressTest's Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static int NumOfClients = 400;
    static int NumOfMessages = 1000;

    static NetworkStream[] Streams = new NetworkStream[NumOfClients];
    static byte[] Message = new byte[1024];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)1024), 0, Message, 0, sizeof(short));
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to run setup");
        Console.ReadLine();

        Setup().Wait();


        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to start sending");
        Console.ReadLine();


        NetworkStream sender = Streams[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumOfMessages; i++)
        {
            sender.WriteAsync(Message, 0, 1024);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task Setup()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Streams.Length; i++)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            tcpClient.Connect("localhost", 4000);
            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            Streams[i] = stream;
            Task.Run(() => CallbackListener(stream));
        }
    }

    static int counter = 0;
    static object objLock = new object();
    static async Task CallbackListener(NetworkStream stream)
    {
        var readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int totalAmountRead;
        short totalLength;

        while (true)
        {
            totalAmountRead = 0;
            while (totalAmountRead < 2)
            {
                totalAmountRead += await stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, totalAmountRead, 2 - totalAmountRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            totalLength = BitConverter.ToInt16(readBuffer, 0);

            while (totalAmountRead < totalLength)
            {
                totalAmountRead += await stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, totalAmountRead, totalLength - totalAmountRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            lock(objLock)
            {
                counter++;
                if (counter % 1000 == 0)
                {
                    // to see progress
                    Console.WriteLine(counter);
                }
            }
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Server's Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = new ServerEngine();
        server.Start(IPAddress.Any, 4000);
    }
}
```

Server's ServerEngine.cs

```
public class ServerEngine
{
    private List<NetworkStream> connectedUsers = new List<NetworkStream>();
    private int processedRequestsAmount = 0;
    private Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    public ServerEngine()
    {
    }

    public void Start(IPAddress ipAddress, int port)
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
        try
        {
            listener.Start();
            AcceptClientsAsync(listener);

            while (true)
            {
                Console.ReadKey(true);
                Console.WriteLine("Processed requests: " + processedRequestsAmount);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            listener.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Server stopped! Press ENTER to close application...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private async Task AcceptClientsAsync(TcpListener listener)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                StartClientListenerAsync(client);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task StartClientListenerAsync(TcpClient client)
    {
        using (client)
        {
            var buf = new byte[1024];
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            lock (connectedUsers)
            {
                connectedUsers.Add(stream);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(connectedUsers.Count + " users connected!");

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    await RecieveMessageAsync(stream, buf).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            connectedUsers.Remove(stream);
            Console.WriteLine("User disconnected.");
        }
    }

    private async Task RecieveMessageAsync(NetworkStream stream, byte[] readBuffer)
    {
        int totalAmountRead = 0;

        // read header (length, 2 bytes total)
        while (totalAmountRead < 2)
        {
            totalAmountRead += await stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, totalAmountRead, 2 - totalAmountRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        short totalLength = BitConverter.ToInt16(readBuffer, 0);

        // read rest of the message
        while (totalAmountRead < totalLength)
        {
            totalAmountRead += await stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, totalAmountRead, totalLength - totalAmountRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        await SendToAll(readBuffer, totalLength).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private async Task SendToAll(byte[] buffer, short totalLength)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(connectedUsers.Count);
        if (processedRequestsAmount == 0)
        {
            sw.Start();
        }

        foreach (NetworkStream stream in connectedUsers)
        {
            tasks.Add(stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

        processedRequestsAmount++;
        if (processedRequestsAmount == 1000)
        {
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Average time for sending 400 messages is {0} ms", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / 1000.0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One point more - in SendToAllAsync you can supress capture ExecutionContext

```
  foreach (NetworkStream stream in connectedUsers)
    {
        ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();
        tasks.Add(stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)); 
    }
```

and please , read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx